# React Native list items one by one from state array

Tags: arrays, react-native, state, expo

I am looking for a method where I can use data from an array and have it shown one item at a time.
Here is my code:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    feed: [{
      username: ["Its_Jess: ", "Haro1d: "],
      caption: ["The New Photoshoot was so much fun!", "Had a great day at the beach"]
    }]
  }
}

renderFeed = () => {
    return this.state.feed.map((card, index) => {
      return (
        <Card>
          <Text key={index}>{card.username}</Text>
          <Text key={index}>{card.caption}</Text>
          </Card>
        )
    })
}

render() {
    return (
       <View>
          {this.renderFeed()}
       </View>
    );
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is for it to have a pattern like

> Its_Jess:
>      The New Photoshoot was so much fun!

.then a separation between this Card

> Haro1d: 
>      Had a great day at the beach

However instead what I'm getting is:

> Its_Jess:Haro1d:
>   The New Photoshoot was so much fun!Had a great day at the beach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this.

NOTE: This is a tutorial for your solution.

```js
const feed = [{
  username: ["Its_Jess: ", "Haro1d: "],
  caption: ["The New Photoshoot was so much fun!", "Had a great day at the beach"]
}];

const App = () => {
  return feed.map((card, index) => {
    return card.username.map((c, i) => {
      if(card.caption[i])
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <span>{c}</span>
            <span>{card.caption[i]}</span>
          </div>
        );
    });
  })
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here is your solution.

**Question: why make the key like `${i}_${index}`?**
when rendering the Feed, the key is like the index. therefore each component should have a different key, so I make the key by 2 indexes(i and index).

```
  renderFeed = () => {
    return this.state.feed.map((card, index) => {
      return card.username.map((username, i) => {
        if (card.caption[i]) {
          return (
            <Card key={`${i}_${index}`}>
              <Text>{username}</Text>
              <Text>{card.caption[i]}</Text>
            </Card>
          );
        }
        return <React.Fragment />;
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: so instead of `state` it is recommended I use `const`?

Comment: no, that's the tutorial for workflow and at the bottom of my answer, I provided your solution.

Comment: when I replace my original function with the one you provided I receive an error saying `unexpected token` as it points to the `return` method in the render function within the whole screen.

Comment: @FrankGully, I updated the answer. I forgot the `/` in `<React.Fragment  />`

Comment: It works! one thing though. Do you mind explaining what the `key={`${i}_${index}`}` means? what do the symbols mean?

Comment: @FrankGully, when rendering the Feed, the key is like the index. therefore each component should have a different key, so I make the key by 2 indexes(i and index). that's all.

Comment: I appreciate you teaching me that. It solved another warning I've been receiving in my project. Thank you